# Javascript simple scroll function problem

Tags: javascript, css, html, scroll

I tried to find a solution here but couldn't find what I was looking for.

Its a simple problem related to the functionality of some JavaScript code.

I simplified my code to be readable by anyone.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>index</title>
<style>
    #my-nav {
        position: sticky;
        top: 0;
        height: 150px;
        background: #000;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <nav id="my-nav"></nav>
    <script>
        navScroll();
        window.onscroll = function () { navScroll() };
        function navScroll(){
            var nav = document.getElementById('my-nav');

            if(document.body.scrollTop > 50 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 50){
                nav.style.height= "40px";
            }
            else {
                nav.style.height="150px";
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now let us add anything after the `nav` tag to test the scroll function.
The function should simply resize the navigation bar when you scroll down some specific pixels and return to its size when you return to the top.

***However, you will see that the function will keep toggling and the navigation bar will keep resizing "continually". (Especially on Firefox, the performance problem will be clearer and we will see that its slow.)***

Comment: you can implement throttle or debounce to limit the execution of function

https://codeburst.io/throttling-and-debouncing-in-javascript-b01cad5c8edf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code modifies page layout as you change height. So, the scrolltop value changes repeatedly. Use `position:fixed` to not collapse layout.

```html
<nav id="my-nav"></nav>
<div id="nav-space"></div>
```

```css
#nav-space {
  height: 200px;
}

#my-nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background: #000;
}
```

Here is working code => https://jsfiddle.net/moorthyrweb/f7py6zex/

Comment: Thank you very much. Your code really helped me. Now I see why resizing elements with "sticky values keeps resizing the space repeatedly and causes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You might suffering with Throttling and Debouncing event crisis.For better understanding JS Event Triggered,These Will Help You i guess:

https://www.sitepoint.com/throttle-scroll-events/

[How to debounce or throttle scroll events in iOS devices ( Safari )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54328355/how-to-debounce-or-throttle-scroll-events-in-ios-devices-safari)

https://codeburst.io/throttling-and-debouncing-in-javascript-b01cad5c8edf